# What is the character that represents a null byte after ASCIIEncoding.GetString(byte[])?

Tags: c#, .net, string, arrays

I have a byte array that may or may not have null bytes at the end of it.  After converting it to a string I have a bunch of blank space at the end.  I tried using Trim() to get rid of it, but it doesn't work.  How can I remove all the blank space at the end of the string after converting the byte array?

I am writing this is C#.

Comment: What are the values in the byte array?  And are you sure that the byte array contains an ASCII string and not Unicode or UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public string TrimNulls(byte[] data)
{
    int rOffset = data.Length - 1;

    for(int i = data.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        rOffset = i;

        if(data[i] != (byte)0) break;            
    }

    return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, rOffset + 1);
}
```

**In the interest of full disclosure**, I'd like to be very clear that this will *only* work reliably for ASCII. For any multi-byte encoding this will crap the bed.

Comment: Please add that your solution works great for ASCII encoding (as the OP requested), but will break horribly for anything else.

Comment: That will work.  Thanks.  i was hoping to be able to do something like Trim on the resulting string, but I guess not.  Thanks!

Comment: Small bug with this solution.  The return value should be:

 return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, rOffset+1);

Otherwise it will cut off the last byte.

Comment: @Brian: I already added that a few minutes ago, but thanks ;)

Answer (score 7):

Trim() does not work in your case, because it only removes spaces, tabs and newlines AFAIK. It does not remove the '\0' character. You could also use something like this:

byte[] bts = ...;

string result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bts).TrimEnd('\0');

Comment: Perhaps not the most eficcient one for me (having 20k of "0"s) but worked as a charm. Thanks